# How to read a certificate chain for OkHttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp, client-certificates, pem

```
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
byte[] keyBytes = Files.readAllBytes((Paths.get("/path/to/chain.pem")));
X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
    new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);

byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/key.pem"));
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
PrivateKey privateKey =  keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec);
HeldCertificate cert = new HeldCertificate.Builder().keyPair(publicKey, privateKey).build();
HandshakeCertificates clientCertificates = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .heldCertificate(cert)
    .build();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(clientCertificates.sslSocketFactory(), clientCertificates.trustManager())
    .build();
```

I'm trying to use an Okhttpclient for client authentication and this is what I currently have. The chain.pem file has multiple certificates of form

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The keyFactory.generatePublic method fails with `Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format` when it tries to parse the certificate chain. How can I parse this certificate chain for the OkhttpClient? Do I have to split the chain into multiple pems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are certificates, not one or even several publickey(s). A certificate contains a publickey, but the certificate is not a publickey and cannot be read as a publickey. Moreover, those certs were issued to you for a reason; if you use the supplied chain of certs (and privatekey) the server will trust them but if you generate your own self-signed cert, even for the same key, which is what your `HeldCertificate.Builder()` would do, the server won't trust that cert because it is not issued by a valid CA. Digital certificates are sometimes analogized to passports; if you have a passport, with your name and picture, issued by your government, other countries (and domestic entities also) will generally accept that as proof of your identify, but if you write your name and the word 'passport' on a piece of paper and paste a picture of yourself, nobody will accept that as proof -- that's what a self-signed certificate is like.

**To read your files** in Java is fairly easy. The certificates are easiest -- that format can be read by `CertificateFactory` directly:

```
byte[] certBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/chain.pem"));
InputStream certstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes);
X509Certificate[] certs = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
    .generateCertificates(certstream) .toArray(new X509Certificate[0]);
certstream.close(); // or use try-resources if you prefer
```

The key may be harder; if it is in PEM format as the name `key.pem` suggests `KeyFactory` (unlike `CertificateFactory`) does not read PEM. If it is **one particular PEM format** namely PKCS8 unencrypted as per [RFC7468 section 10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468#section-10) -- marked (as shown there) by `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and similar `END` *with no other words between BEGIN/END and PRIVATE KEY* -- you can convert it as follows:

```
byte[] pkeyPEM = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/path/to/key.pem"));
byte[] pkeyDER = Base64.getDecoder().decode( new String(pkeyBytes)
    .replaceAll("-----(BEGIN|END) PRIVATE KEY-----","").replaceAll("\r?\n","") ); 
RSAPrivateKey privateKey =  (RSAPrivateKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
    .generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkeyDER));
```

However, there are at least a dozen other PEM formats used for privatekeys that Java cannot read directly. *Most* of these are used by OpenSSL, and if the `BEGIN` and `END` lines say `ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY` or `{RSA|DSA|EC} PRIVATE KEY` you can use `openssl` commandline to convert that to the format Java can handle:

```
openssl pkey -in badPEM -out goodPEM # only 1.0.0 up but that is now very common
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in badPEM -out goodPEM # even old versions
```

Morever if you add `-outform der` to either of those (and please change the filename accordingly to avoid confusion), you no longer need the de-PEM step, you can put the `Files.readAllBytes` result directly in `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`. If your key file is anything else, it's more difficult or possibly impossible; you'll have to provide more details.

**To use in OkHttp** frankly [this API](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp-tls/okhttp3.tls/) looks to me like it was designed by people who don't know what they're doing; it makes no sense at all to use a `KeyPair` together with a `Certificate`. But logically this *should* work:

```
RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) certs[0].getPublicKey(); 
if( ! publicKey.getModulus().equals( privateKey.getModulus() ) )
    throw new Exception ("key does not match cert"); // or other error handling
HeldCertificate client1 = new HeldCertificate( new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey), certs[0]);
HandshakeCertificates client2 = new HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .addPlatformTrustedCertificates() // or more specific if necessary
    .heldCertificate(client1,Arrays.copyOfRange(certs,1,certs.length) )
    .build();
// use client2 as you do now to set sslSocketFactory and trustManager
```